# Need to blank screen but not sleep and still register touch events

Tags: java, android

I'm having some issues with an app where I want to completely blank the screen, but still register `touch` events and perform actions based on them (including unblanking the screen on a long press).

I've tried to do this by simply dimming the screen using the `screenBrightness` parameter in `WindowManager.LayoutParams` however setting it to `0` blanks it and causes it to ignore touches, and anything else dims it but not nearly enough (I want it to basically appear off).

Any hints on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!